# Single or Multi Page Application, which one?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I try to decide between Single Page Application or other one using AngularJS in client side. What do i have to consider for it? How Single or multi page application affect performance on concurrent client or does it effect?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will choose to design your application with **single-page** concept - then most of your css/js files will load only, the else logic will be done using javascript(templating, calling backend, etc).Single page approach also requires to have specific backend - in most cases there are RESTful service with xml,json endpoints.For example, when you have single page - and you want to get information about some(for example) product, you need to call your backend with url -

[http://{backend-host}/api/products/1](http://%7Bbackend-host%7D/api/products/1)

and backend should return(example):

```
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name" : "product1"
 }
```

You will do this call using angularJS and handle all templating on frontend side.

If you will choose **multipage** - in most cases you would need to do templating on backend side.Comming back to our example with products, if you will need to get information about product, you can call your backend in the way.

[http://{backend-host}/products/1](http://%7Bbackend-host%7D/products/1)

And it should return fully rendered(html) page for you.

SPA is like modern approach - you can divide your application in two parts - frontend and backend.As soon as you will divide, you can choose to use JAVA for your backend, and Angular.js for your frontend.

Now you understand the difference ?)

Comment: @user1811660 could you set my answer as correct answer ?Of course, if it's ok for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ivan. Actually i am not asking the difference. Why do i have to choose spa, or multi page otherwise? How is it affect to the clients?

Comment: SPA is like modern approach - you can divide your application in two parts - frontend and backend.As soon as you will divide, you can choose to use JAVA for your backend, and Angular.js for your frontend.